# How to set Commerce 2 confirmation email in .env file?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, multi-environment, plugin-craftcommerce2

We're just in the process of upgrading from Craft 2 with Commerce 1 to Craft 3 and Commerce 2. One of the issues we had before was that the client was getting confirmation emails for test orders.

Is it possible to set the confirmation email destination in the .env file so our team can set themselves as the target emails for their own local testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the `testToEmailAddress` config setting in your `config.php`? As this will send all emails to a single address.

`'testToEmailAddress' => getenv('TEST_TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS')`

Then in your `.env` set:

`TEST_TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS="email@email.com"`